# can I hide variables on a inheritance hierarchy in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am trying to create a program where there is a method with a formula.This formula is exported to other classes, but each class uses different variables.

when I use my program the mothods and variables are exported and I only want to export the method (formula) from Bronce class to Silver class.

If I cannot hide variables, how canI overcome this problem??

I am new at java

**Bronze Class**

```
public  class Bronze  {

    // ----------------- Atributes -----------------------

    private static final double costDay = 0.12;

    public int dayMinutes;      // daytime telphone minutes used

    public double dayTimeCost;  //Total daytime calls cost

    // ------------- CONSTRUCTORS (inputs) ---------------

    public Bronze(int theDayMinutes ) {  
    dayMinutes = theDayMinutes; 
    }
    // ------------------ METHODS ------------------------
    // Calculate Total daytime calls cost
    public double calcDayTimeCost() {

        dayTimeCost = dayMinutes * costDay;
        return dayTimeCost;
    }

    //toString method to override that in Object
    public String toString(){
    return("\nCost of daytime calls = " + costDay + "/min"+
        "\n\nTotal daytime calls cost = " + dayTimeCost + 
 "\n" 
         );
    }

    //Returns the type of account
    public String type(){
    return "Bronze";
    }
}
```

**Silver Class**

```
public class Silver extends Bronze {

    private static final double costDay = 0.22;

    public Silver(int theDayMinutes ) {
    super(theDayMinutes );

  }
    //Returns the type of account
    public String type(){
    return "Silver";
    }

}
```

**Main Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountUser {

    // ------------------- FIELDS ------------------------    

    // Create instance of Scanner class
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // variables
    public static Bronze bron;
    public static Silver silv;

    public static int dayMinutes;

    // ------------------ METHODS ------------------------  

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // Input dayMinutes (with error message)
        do{
        System.out.print("Please daytime telphone minutes used --> ");
        dayMinutes  = input.nextInt();
        if  ( dayMinutes <= 0){System.out.print("\n" + "Input value outside the range!!!" + "\n");}
        }while( dayMinutes <= 0);


        // Create new Bronze instance
        bron = new Bronze(dayMinutes);
        silv = new Silver(dayMinutes);
        // Calculate scheme1, scheme2
        bron.calcDayTimeCost();
        silv.calcDayTimeCost();


    System.out.println(bron);
    System.out.println(silv);
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, only methods can be overriden

Comment: "Silver extends Bronze" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: How can I overcome this problem by using inheritance?? @Berger

Comment: It would make sense that silver and bronze both extend Metal, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make costDay a parameter to the method. public double calcDayTimeCost(double costDay) then call it with silv.calcDayTimeCost(0.22)

Comment: but how can I invoke costDay again for String toString? @BrianPipa

Answer (score 0):

While the keyword `overriding` is wrong here because it does not apply for class fields, the concept of `shadowing` still applies.

Right now when you invoke `calcDayTimeCost` on your `Silver` object it uses the `super` field of `costDay`.

You have to change it to

```
 protected double costDay = 0.12; // Bronze class
```

and

```
 public Silver(int theDayMinutes ) {
    super(theDayMinutes );
    super.costDay = 0.12;
  }
```

Comment: when I change costDay in each class to protected double, I still get the same results, do I have to change something elese? @Murat K.

Comment: @dr.loop What do you get in yout `System.out.println()`?

Comment: Bronce `Cost of daytime calls = 0.12/min`
`Total daytime calls cost = 12.0`
  Silver                                 
`Cost of daytime calls = 0.12/min`
`Total daytime calls cost = 12.0`

Comment: @dr.loop My bad I forgot something. See my answer.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you agin, but I am still getting the same outputs